# hypergraph support in boost library

Tags: c++, boost

Does anyone know if c++ boost library supports hypergraph? 
I am trying to solve a subgraph isomorphism problem. I know boost has nice functionality for this, but the graph is a hypergraph.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have used boost's vf2 subraph isomorphism on a hypergraph problem by transforming the hypergraph to a graph:

- Create a vertex in a new graph for each vertex in your hypergraph.  Associate these vertices with a type 'V'
- For each hyperedge in the hypergraph, create a node in the new graph, associate it with a type 'E' and create an edge in the new graph to each vertex that corresponds to a hypergraph-vertex that was incident to the hyperedge
- In the vf2 algorithm's node-matching function, restrict vertices in the graph and search-pattern to match only if they have the same types E or V.

Answer (score 0):

No they don't. Boost graph library is only for graphs.